# Getting Error in Dependency Resolution during installing vlc media player on centos7?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, vlc

I was trying to install vlc on centos7 using `yum install vlc` as root user, But didn't succeed. I think previously I install wrong repository. I am getting following error. Following is only part installation message, where I got error. Whole part is after this

```
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libnotify.so.1()(64bit)
           Available: libnotify-0.5.0-1.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libnotify.so.1()(64bit)
           Installed: libnotify-0.7.5-7.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libnotify.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
           Available: gnutls-2.8.5-14.el6_5.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
           Installed: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7.x86_64 (@base)
              ~libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
           Available: gnutls-2.8.5-14.el6_5.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
           Installed: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7.x86_64 (@base)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_10)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_12)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_8)(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: libudev-147-2.57.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libproxy.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: libproxy-0.3.0-10.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libproxy.so.0()(64bit)
           Installed: libproxy-0.4.11-6.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libproxy.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Available: libmtp-0.3.7-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Available: libmtp-1.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Installed: libmtp-1.1.6-3.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libmtp.so.9()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

**Whole message on terminal during installation.**

```
root@localhost neelabh]# yum install vlc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/jgillich/brackets/fedora--/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: epel.mirror.srv.co.ge
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * linuxtech-release: linuxsoft.cern.ch
 * rpmforge: ftp.riken.jp
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vlc.x86_64 0:2.0.7-10.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libswscale.so.2(LIBSWSCALE_2)(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpostproc.so.52(LIBPOSTPROC_52)(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavutil.so.52(LIBAVUTIL_52)(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavformat.so.54(LIBAVFORMAT_54)(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavcodec.so.54(LIBAVCODEC_54)(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb-keysyms.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libx264.so.130()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libva.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libva-x11.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libupnp.so.6()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
Package libudev-147-2.57.el6.x86_64 is obsoleted by systemd-libs-208-20.el7_1.2.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtwolame.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff.so.3()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libthreadutil.so.6()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libswscale.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libschroedinger-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libproxy.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpostproc.so.52()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnotify.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmtp.so.8()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpeg2.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmpcdec.so.5()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmodplug.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libminizip.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmatroska.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmad.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libliveMedia.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblirc_client.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libkate.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libixml.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgroupsock.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfribidi.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfaad.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libenca.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libebml.so.3()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdvbpsi.so.7()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdirac_encoder.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdirac_decoder.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdca.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdc1394.so.22()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrystalhd.so.3()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcddb.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavutil.so.52()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavformat.so.54()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavcodec.so.54()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libass.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liba52.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libUsageEnvironment.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libSDL_image-1.2.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libBasicUsageEnvironment.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package SDL_image.x86_64 0:1.2.12-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package compat-libtiff3.x86_64 0:3.9.4-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package enca.x86_64 0:1.14-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package fribidi.x86_64 0:0.19.4-6.el7 will be installed
---> Package liba52.x86_64 0:0.7.4-10.el6 will be installed
---> Package libass.x86_64 0:0.10.0-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libavcodec54.x86_64 0:1.2.6-61.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libopencore-amrwb.so.0()(64bit) for package: libavcodec54-1.2.6-61.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libopencore-amrnb.so.0()(64bit) for package: libavcodec54-1.2.6-61.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libx264.so.142()(64bit) for package: libavcodec54-1.2.6-61.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxvidcore.so.4()(64bit) for package: libavcodec54-1.2.6-61.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxavs.so.1()(64bit) for package: libavcodec54-1.2.6-61.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmp3lame.so.0()(64bit) for package: libavcodec54-1.2.6-61.el7.x86_64
---> Package libavformat54.x86_64 0:1.2.6-61.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: librtmp.so.0()(64bit) for package: libavformat54-1.2.6-61.el7.x86_64
---> Package libavutil52.x86_64 0:2.2.1-65.el7 will be installed
---> Package libcddb.x86_64 0:1.3.2-12.el7 will be installed
---> Package libcrystalhd.x86_64 0:20110917-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libdc1394.x86_64 0:2.2.2-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libdca0.x86_64 0:0.0.5-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package libdirac.x86_64 0:1.0.2-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libdvbpsi7.x86_64 0:0.2.2-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libebml.x86_64 0:1.2.1-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libfaad2.x86_64 1:2.7-18.el7 will be installed
---> Package libkate.x86_64 0:0.4.1-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package libmad.x86_64 0:0.15.1b-6.el6 will be installed
---> Package libmatroska.x86_64 0:1.2.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package libmodplug.x86_64 1:0.8.8.5-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libmpcdec.x86_64 0:1.2.6-12.el7 will be installed
---> Package libmpeg2.x86_64 0:0.5.1-5.el6 will be installed
---> Package libpostproc52.x86_64 0:2.2.1-65.el7 will be installed
---> Package libswscale2.x86_64 0:2.2.1-65.el7 will be installed
---> Package libtwolame.x86_64 0:0.3.13-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package libupnp.x86_64 0:1.6.19-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libva-x11_1.x86_64 0:1.3.1-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package libva1.x86_64 0:1.3.1-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package libx264_130.x86_64 0:0.130-0.20130531.1.el6 will be installed
---> Package lirc-libs.x86_64 0:0.9.1a-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package live.x86_64 0:2012.02.04-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package minizip.x86_64 0:1.2.7-13.el7 will be installed
---> Package schroedinger.x86_64 0:1.0.11-4.el7 will be installed
---> Package vlc.x86_64 0:2.0.7-10.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
Package libudev-147-2.57.el6.x86_64 is obsoleted by systemd-libs-208-20.el7_1.2.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: libproxy.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnotify.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmtp.so.8()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
---> Package xcb-util-keysyms.x86_64 0:0.3.9-5.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmp3lame.x86_64 0:3.98.4-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package libopencore-amr.x86_64 0:0.1.2-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package librtmp0.x86_64 0:2.3-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libx264_142.x86_64 0:0.142-20_20140406.2245.el7 will be installed
---> Package libxavs1.x86_64 0:0.1.51-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libxvidcore.x86_64 0:1.3.2-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package vlc.x86_64 0:2.0.7-10.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libudev.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
Package libudev-147-2.57.el6.x86_64 is obsoleted by systemd-libs-208-20.el7_1.2.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: libproxy.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnotify.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmtp.so.8()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit) for package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libnotify.so.1()(64bit)
           Available: libnotify-0.5.0-1.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libnotify.so.1()(64bit)
           Installed: libnotify-0.7.5-7.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libnotify.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
           Available: gnutls-2.8.5-14.el6_5.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libgnutls.so.26()(64bit)
           Installed: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7.x86_64 (@base)
              ~libgnutls.so.28()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
           Available: gnutls-2.8.5-14.el6_5.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libgnutls.so.26(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
           Installed: gnutls-3.3.8-12.el7.x86_64 (@base)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_1_4)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_10)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_12)(64bit)
              ~libgnutls.so.28(GNUTLS_2_8)(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libudev.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: libudev-147-2.57.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libudev.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libproxy.so.0()(64bit)
           Available: libproxy-0.3.0-10.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libproxy.so.0()(64bit)
           Installed: libproxy-0.4.11-6.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libproxy.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: vlc-2.0.7-10.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
           Requires: libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Available: libmtp-0.3.7-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
               libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Available: libmtp-1.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-vlc)
               libmtp.so.8()(64bit)
           Installed: libmtp-1.1.6-3.el7.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
              ~libmtp.so.9()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Good background information. What's the question, please?

Comment: @roaima, Thanks for pointing out, I was trying to install VLC media Player for video but did' succeed due to installing wrong repository, I think..

Comment: So is this now sorted?

Comment: You can try enabling [Nux Desktop repository](http://li.nux.ro/repos.html), see also [this](http://ask.xmodulo.com/enable-nux-dextop-repository-centos-rhel.html) and I think you will succefully install vlc.

Comment: @taliezin, Still I am getting the same problem..`Error: Package: 4:mplayer-1.2-93_snap20140413.el7.x86_64 (atrpms) Requires: libx264.so.142()(64bit)Available: libx264_142-0.142-20_20140406.2245.el6_90.x86_64 (atrpms)             libx264.so.142()(64bit)Available: libx264_142-0.142-20_20140406.2245.el7.x86_64 (atrpms)               libx264.so.142()(64bit) Available: x264-libs-0.142-4.20140423gite260ea5.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)               libx264.so.142()(64bit) Available: x264-libs-.142-7.20140728gitaf8e768.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)        libx264.so.142()(64bit)

Comment: try first yum update.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar issue when installing VLC on CentOS 7.  The following works for me.  I disabled rpmforge and left epel repository on.  I googled a bit and found someone saying epel and rpmforge don't well together.